# How to have Free text custom slot type on AWS lex

Tags: amazon-web-services, chatbot, amazon-lex, slot

I need a slot type that accepts any type of input, The slot I want to point is to get review feedback from my clients.

After looking on with all possible option the only way to achieve is with training data on custom slot type that all search results provides as a solution, That is totally a nightmare with my case now.

I have provided 130+ sample data but it didn't work, 95% fails.

I also have some more slots that needs free text slot.

Do any one achieved free text, Need Help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will definitely want to parse the input and validate it in a Lambda Function by checking the `event.inputTranscript`

More details on how to do that in either of my other answers here:

[What is Amazon Lex inbuilt slot type for description or notes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62058978/what-is-amazon-lex-inbuilt-slot-type-for-description-or-notes/62079381#62079381)

[AWS Lex + Lambda - Intercepting all of next user response regardless of context - without defining sample utterances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51101099/aws-lex-lambda-intercepting-all-of-next-user-response-regardless-of-context/51111523#51111523)

Comment: I am parsing the request.event.inputTranscript for the free text slot on my lambda and assigning it to responset.recentIntentSummaryView.slots, Also forcing to next slotType/Intent with responset.recentIntentSummaryView.slotToElicit .

This works but not happy :(

Comment: I'm glad it works but why not happy about it? This is how Lex development is. If you want an open-ended slot, then you are not using Lex's NLU (natural language understanding), and this is exactly how you bypass the NLU and build your own parsing for those special slots. You are doing it the right way. Use the NLU on intents and slots that have specific values to parse, and use Lambda to parse the inputTranscipt yourself for open-ended inputs. Using them together gives you finer control of your bot. So if this answer worked for you, then you should upvote and/or accept it.

Comment: If Lex provides a built-in slot type for Free slot bypassing NLU, That would be more good so that handling them on lambda is not needed. Hope AWS Lex comes with this in the future. Thank You All:)

Answer (score 0):

The closest you would find to this functionality is a slot you can use that would allow you to capture free text - [`AMAZON.SearchQuery`](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#searchquery).

You should go through the documentation for this slot type though as it comes with caveats for how it can be used, and test it before going ahead.

Other than this take a look at the [5 Techniques to Replace AMAZON.LITERAL and Improve Skill Accuracy](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/a3142024-75cf-46bb-924a-0ab3524a5c07/5-techniques-to-replace-amazon-literal-and-improve-skill-accuracy) blog post which covers techniques that can be used.

Comment: But Amazon Lex doesn't support the AMAZON.LITERAL or the AMAZON.SearchQuery built-in slot types. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/howitworks-builtins-slots.html , Any hack,  Also with 5 Techniques to Replace AMAZON.LITERAL my need of free text cant be achieved, I need lex to accept any text user provides unless that matches a utterances.

Comment: It is indeed available: "For a list of available built-in slot types, see the [Slot Type Reference](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html) in the Alexa Skills Kit documentation.", the documentation links to this :). Unfortunately other than this there are no other options, as Lex is built to match intents rather than dictate text :(

Comment: Below the statement  "For a list of available built-in slot types, see the Slot Type Reference in the Alexa Skills Kit documentation." you can see a note that tells AMAZON.SearchQuery note supported for lex,  :((  Lex is built to match only intents. Almost close to complete my work this free text stops me and now I'm afraid :(

Comment: Ah I did not notice that, unfortunately then unless you can match the intents. I see theres a attribute of `inputTranscript` in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html. Don't suppose thats any help?

Answer (score 0):

Check with this article we have a python code that generates slot type value.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/create-a-translator-chatbot-using-amazon-translate-and-amazon-lex/

Now I have 1000 values, But I am facing a different issue.
[Slot type works different for slots AWS LEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63705113/slot-type-works-different-for-slots-aws-lex/63722200)