# Slot type works different for slots AWS LEX

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-lex, alexa-slot

I have two slots with the same slot type but they work differently.

1. Slot name **slotOneBOne** with **free text** slot type does not accept **ok** but Slot name **slotOneBTwo** with same **free text** slot type accept **ok**

[image: e fre]

[image]

2. Slot name **startMessage** with **free text** slot type accept **let's do** but Slot name **slotOneDOne** with same **free text** slot type does not accept **let's do**

[image]

3. Some slots only accept the exact slot type value that is used to train.

Slot Type free text having 1000 values, I used this article where we have a code that gets freetext from Python https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/create-a-translator-chatbot-using-amazon-translate-and-amazon-lex/

[image]

I am using Return parameters to client.

Need help :(

Comment: Are you using Lambda?

Comment: No I am not and I am doing return parameters to client. For the first three intent it was working perfect after doing the forth intent this problem started.

Comment: For the first three intent with same slot type it was working perfect after doing the forth intent this problem started, Now only first intent with slot type freetext accept random text but the other three goes with this three set of issue i mentioned above. I created new bot but getting the same.

Comment: I can get you more detail if you want, I am stuck so badly on this.

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to say without really knowing how your custom slot types are configured and what sort of Lambda's are supporting the bot.
With regards to question 3; I would hazard a guess that you're using an enumeration for the slot which is why only the exact values are detected correctly.

Comment: I am not using Lambda, I go with return parameters to client and for all the 3 I am using the custom slot type Freetext with Expand Values selected.

Comment: Updated the Slot type with image

Comment: Quoting from the blog post shared 
"I overload the slot values of Amazon Lex to accept any input by providing a lot of slot values, much more than what you might normally assign for a slot. This does cause some limitations in terms of what additional slots the chatbot can respond to. Effectively everything will match the custom slot after the source and target languages have been set so I use custom logic in the Lambda function instead"
I would hazard a guess that using that many FreeText slots is confusing Lex and leading to unpredictable behaviour. Perhaps Lex isn't suited to your use case