# How can I collect a users description in Amazon Lex and send it through email?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am developing a chatbot with Amazon Lex and I want to collect a description of a customers issue, save it to a variable, and send it through email. How can I implement this functionality?

Comment: Unfortunately Lex does not have a generic "Any" slot type that can capture what is essentially free-form text. You can, however, use a Lambda for slot input verification and simply collect the user's input into the relevant slot's value in within the session and/or request variables. You may need to use a variety of sentences as training data for a custom slot type.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that I was able to solve by creating a [Lambda function to access the user's inputTranscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63540192/how-to-have-free-text-custom-slot-type-on-aws-lex).

You basically provide the Lex Bot with some sample utterances (which usually will capture part of what the user has said) and in your Lambda function, access the the `event.inputTranscript`. This is the last thing the user has typed exactly as they typed it.

My project was written in NodeJS so I used [Nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/) and the Gmail API to send the inputTranscript in an email. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-rcRf7yswfM&ab_channel=yoursTRULY) is the video tutorial I followed at the time. It'll show you how to set everything up :)

If you are using Python, you can use the built-in library [smtplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html) to send emails. Although I'm sure there are other options as well.

Hope this helps!